# The mariadbd process is at over 140% CPU utilisation despite a high innodb_buffer_pool_size value

Tags: optimization, mariadb

I have a Plesk Ubuntu 22.04 server with 120GB RAM and mariadb 10.6.16 that I use to run the database for a single website. The database alone is about 8GB but despite all the optimisations I've made mariadb is still running at over 140% of CPU. This results in slow website response times.

I've done quite a few Google searches and optimised PHP FPM and MySQL but despite all this the speed of the website is still slow and I'm pointing the finger at mariadb whose process is at more than 140% of the processor. I'll leave you the screenshot below.

[mariadb process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx7ns.png)

PHP FPM configuration

I setted :

```
pm.max_children = 90
pm.max_requests = 200
pm = static
memory_limit = 10240M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
```

MariaDB configuration

In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, i setted theses values

```
[mysqld] sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
loose-local-infile=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 96G
innodb_log_file_size = 12G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 512M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 4k
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 6000
```

It is also curious but in the screenshot of the memory bellow the cached part (beige color) is too small.
[Memory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Xlu.png)

The server itself was working well in a 64Gb Ubuntu 20.04 server without problem. But since this migration it's slow. Even though we passed the RAM from 64Gb to 120Go in the Ubuntu 22.04 server.

Have anyone already faced this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

---

Here are additionnal informations based on comments :
The server CPU is 24 x AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
The hard drive is NVMe

[image: Top command]

[image: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;]

[image]

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

| InnoDB |      |
=====================================
2024-02-06 09:18:33 0x7fd0721fe640 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 55 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 0 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 386065 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 386059
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 5295351
Purge done for trx's n:o < 5295349 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 1
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01d0880), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cdc80), not started
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cb080), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c8480), not started
mysql tables in use 6, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c4d80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cbb80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c4280), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01d1380), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cd180), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01ce780), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cc680), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c3780), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c0b80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01d1e80), not started
mysql tables in use 2, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c9a80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cfd80), not started
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01cf280), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01ca580), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c7980), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c2c80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c6e80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c2180), not started
mysql tables in use 5, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c8f80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c6380), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c5880), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fe8c01c1680), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
406980 OS file reads, 1500489 OS file writes, 309011 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 1.07 writes/s, 0.56 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 10381178784
Log flushed up to   10381178282
Pages flushed up to 9758411800
Last checkpoint at  9758411788
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
1500490 log i/o's done, 1.07 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 103213432832
Dictionary memory allocated 613451784
Buffer pool size   6230016
Free buffers       5820886
Database pages     409130
Old database pages 151006
Modified db pages  21938
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.352
Max dirty pages percent: 90.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0
Pages made young 1300160, not young 5227092
0.04 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 406341, created 12733, written 0
0.00 reads/s, 0.02 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 409130, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=0, Main thread ID=0, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 774791, updated 948664, deleted 367, read 777328684815
0.85 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1854176.96 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

The other commands are too long results to be insert in the description based on the limit fixed by Stackexchange.

Other Informations :

**SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;** https://justpaste.it/4iip0

**SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;** https://justpaste.it/d9k81

**STATUS;** https://justpaste.it/fk95g

**ulimit -a** https://justpaste.it/bc50r

Comment: First step, disable query cache, it could be adding to CPU usage without gain. The small cached part could be from MariaDB-10.6 innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT is default. You can't throw memory at the problem and expect it to be faster.  Include `show global status` in your question. Also enable the slow query log with a `long_query_time` of less than 1 (second) and see what queries are there. This might be solved with a few indexes or better queries.

Comment: We have to see the worst queries to help you.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If your database is really 8G, Innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G would be fine.  Throwing 90GB at pool size just introduces wasted overhead trying to keep up with something that will not exist until you have significant growth.

Comment: We really need to know how many CORES are on your hosting server.  Max number children is influenced by your number of cores.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for your replies. @WilsonHauck i added some information in the post. But i can't add more because of limits of description size.

Comment: And that is the very reason we request you use free services of justpaste.it and share the link with us, to avoid this specific situation.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) STATUS; not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS; for your server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  Thanks for posting the other data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @WilsonHauck. I have added the other informations thought justpaste.it

Comment: @NelsonNokimi  The A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS posted is for 912 seconds of uptime ( about 15 minutes ). Your STATUS report is for 33 minutes of uptime.  B) Was a stress test running during most of these 33 minutes?  Never seen 12 million queries run in 33 minutes on a production system.  C) Can you repost both requests after minimum of 24 hours of uptime for analysis? If not, we can use what you have provided, just for FUN.

Comment: We also need from OS Command Prompt, text results posted from  ulimit -a  report so we are aware of the OS limits your server is working with.

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck. I added the ulimit -a in the descriptions. I also installed a redis server but for now not seem to speed up the site loading.

Comment: Do you want me to go ahead with the workload analysis for STATUS reported for just 912 seconds of uptime?  Makes no sense to me, but I can do it for you just for FUN.  Thanks for the ulimit posting.

Comment: What is in the slowlog?

Comment: Nelson, Please post last 100 lines of your Slow Query Log for all of us to see.  Thanks

Comment: Nelson, See my Answer of earlier today that should provide much relief with unnecessary wasted effort, when applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much for your response.

I solve my problem by taking a Dedicated server instead of VPS.

The old VPS was :
120Go RAM
24 Core AMD CPU
NVMe as storage
Ubuntu 22.04

The new is :
64Go RAM
18 Core Intel CPU
NVMe as storage
Ubuntu 22.04

About Mariadb optimization, i used the config below and the website load very better

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 45G
innodb_log_file_size = 10G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1G
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = OFF
innodb_purge_threads = 8
innodb_page_cleaners = 8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 6000
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 256M
```

I think that it was a problem with the VPS.

Comment: Congratulations on going to a dedicated server.  A managed Dedicated Server I hope,  to allow someone else the joys of BackUp management, Software Updates, etc.  View profile and get in touch when your new server starts to struggle with performance.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions for your OS Command Prompt to consider,

```
ulimit -n 128000  # from 1024 to enable more Open Files / handles
```

This is a dynamic variable and after testing will need to be made persistent across OS stop/start cycles.  We can assist.

Suggestions to consider for your 10.6.16 MariaDB my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G  # from ~ 84G until your DB grows significantly.
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to use more of your available NVME IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=16K  # from 4G to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 3,203,149
read_buffer_size=1M  # from 2M to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 1,872,344
```

There are many other opportunities to improve your configuration and reduce CPU busy percentage.

Comment: Nelson, Have suggestions been applied?  Your perception of speed - better/worse?  Is CPU % down under 140 most of the time?

Answer (score 0):

```
Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
```

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
- 120 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 00:15:12; Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.
- 6.19e+3 QPS

**The More Important Issues:**

Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.  The following analysis will not be very useful because of having run for only 15 minutes.

6,190 queries per second with take a lot of CPU time.  But is the qps normally that high?  Or is this just during startup?

Suggested setting changes:

```
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0    -- since you have SSD (NVME)
slow_query_log = ON
long_query_time = 1
```

**Details and other observations:**

`( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 0 + 0 + 400094 + 0 + 0 + 0 ) / 200 / 912 = 219.3%` -- This *may* be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the hardware can handle it.

`( table_open_cache ) = 8,000` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,536` -- innodb_lru_scan_depth is a very poorly named variable. A better name would be innodb_free_page_target_per_buffer_pool. It is a number of pages InnoDB tries to keep free in each buffer pool instance to speed up read and page creation operations.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 4,791,284 * 16384 / 81920M = 91.4%` -- buffer pool free
-- buffer_pool_size is bigger than working set; could decrease it

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky. Use 2000 if using SSD drive.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 4,791,284 / 5191680 = 92.3%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 85899345920) is bigger than necessary?

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( innodb_change_buffering ) = innodb_change_buffering = none`
-- Pre-5.6.11 / 5.5.31, there was a bug that made ="changes" a safer option. MariaDB 10.5.15 is moving toward "none" and deprecating in 10.9

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 6,560,088,064 / 81920M = 7.6%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( innodb_doublewrite ) = innodb_doublewrite = OFF` -- ON leads to extra I/O, but extra safety in crash.
-- OFF is OK for FusionIO, Galera, Replicas, ZFS, EXT4.

`( innodb_log_buffer_size ) = 1024M` -- Suggest 2MB-64MB, and at least as big as biggest blob set in transactions.
-- Adjust innodb_log_buffer_size (now 1073741824).

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 912 / 60 * 16384M / 4567040 = 57,177` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB. Be sure to also change my.cnf
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 17179869184). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = innodb_flush_neighbors = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( ( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime / innodb_io_capacity ) = ( 400094 + 0 ) / 912 / 200 = 219.3%` -- If > 100%, need more io_capacity.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the drives can handle it.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor. Limits write IO requests per second (IOPS).
-- For starters: HDD: 200; SSD: 2000.

`( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 2` -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 0)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( innodb_purge_threads ) = 8` -- Number of threads to clean up history list.
-- If you have a lot of writes, recommend 4 in versions 5.6 and 10.0 or later.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( bulk_insert_buffer_size ) = 8 / 122880M = 0.01%` -- Buffer for multi-row INSERTs and LOAD DATA
-- Too big could threaten RAM size. Too small could hinder such operations.

`( tmp_table_size ) = 512M` -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 536870912) to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Uptime_since_flush_status ) = 912 = 15m 12s` -- How long (in seconds) since FLUSH STATUS (or server startup).
-- GLOBAL STATUS has not been gathered long enough to get reliable suggestions for many of the issues. Fix what you can, then come back in a several hours.

`( Uptime ) = 912 = 15m 12s` -- How long (in seconds) the server has been running.
-- The system has not been up long enough to get reliable suggestions for many of the issues. Fix what you can, then come back with fresh values after the system has been running several hours.

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 37 / 500 = 7.4%` -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 500), it is good not to have that setting too high.

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 100 / 37 = 270.3%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

`( thread_pool_max_threads ) = 65,536` -- One of many settings for MariaDB's thread pooling
-- Lower the value.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 0
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
(Com_select + Qcache_hits) / (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) = 1,469
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free = 4.79e+6
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 5.19e+6
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 641.8%
Memory_used = 68.6%
Memory_used_initial = 84,228.8MB
Open_streams = 4
innodb_lru_scan_depth / innodb_io_capacity = 7.68
innodb_purge_batch_size = 1,000
max_heap_table_size = 512MB
max_user_connections = 100
min(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size) = 512MB
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 222
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Innodb_have_snappy = ON
Slave_heartbeat_period = 0
Slave_received_heartbeats = 0
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
character_set_system = utf8mb3
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_use_native_aio = OFF
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
old_mode = UTF8_IS_UTF8MB3
optimizer_trace = enabled=off
sql_slave_skip_counter = 0
```